# Can't compile tikz pictures when packages mdwtab and syntax are included

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, mdwtools

I have a strange dilemma that I cannot resolve. I am including three additional packages than what I typically would include:

1. `tikz` -- for state diagrams
2. `mdwtab` and `syntax` for Context-Free-Grammars

When I include these three packages together, LaTex will not let me compile and I do not know why. If I simply remove one or the other, everything is ok. Here is the error message I get when I have both packages included:

```
ERROR: Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text>
                \par
l.32    \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)
                                               {$q_0$};
--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

The following shows a simple example including both packages. As soon as I comment out the packages `mdwtab` and `syntax` everything compiles.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,ctable,booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{syntax}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                             
% Commands                                                                                                                                                                   
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                             
\newcommand{\justif}[2]{&{#1}&\text{#2}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Pushdown Automata}

 \begin{grammar}\centering
     <S> $\rightarrow$ 0S1 | $\epsilon$
 \end{grammar}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (q_2) [below=of q_1] {$q_2$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_3) [left=of q_2] {$q_3$};
   \path[->]
    (q_0) edge node {$\epsilon,\epsilon \to \$$} (q_1)
    (q_1) edge [loop above] node {$0,\epsilon\to 0$} ()
          edge node {$1,0\to\epsilon$} (q_2)
    (q_2) edge [loop right] node {$1,0\to\epsilon$} ()
          edge node {$\epsilon,\$\to\epsilon$} (q_3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

- What is the issue here and how can I get this to compile so that I can get my pdf?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `syntax` package makes the underscore character active so that underscores can be used outside of math mode (always a dangerous strategy). So the problem is caused by the fact that your node labels have underscores in them.  The simplest way to resolve this is to undo the trickery that `syntax` does to the underscore in the `tikzpicture` environment.  This can be done easily using the `\AtBeginEnvironment` facility of the `etoolbox` package. (I also made your example a bit more minimal.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usetikzlibrary{
automata
,positioning}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\catcode`\_=8}
 \begin{document}
\section*{Pushdown Automata}

 \begin{grammar}\centering
     <S> $\rightarrow$ 0S1 | $\epsilon$
 \end{grammar}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
  \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
  \node[state] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state] (q_2) [below=of q_1] {$q_2$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_3) [left=of q_2] {$q_3$};
   \path[->]
    (q_0) edge node {$\epsilon,\epsilon \to \$$} (q_1)
    (q_1) edge [loop above] node {$0,\epsilon\to 0$} ()
          edge node {$1,0\to\epsilon$} (q_2)
    (q_2) edge [loop right] node {$1,0\to\epsilon$} ()
          edge node {$\epsilon,\$\to\epsilon$} (q_3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What else can you recommend?

Comment: What do you mean? Does this document compile with the same error as you get with yours? If I remove all the underscores from your node labels in your document it compiles (without any other modifications).  So you need to be a bit more specific.